# Trouble sending a float array using void pointers

Tags: c

**Hey guys i'm having trouble casting my void pointer array to point to my float array,
i want my void pointer to point to the array of floats
so void[0]=float[0]
i know that a void ptr and float  are not the same size so i cannot assign it in this manner
void[0]=float[0]
how do i tackle this issue?
Thanks!

```
void *ptr[5];
float arr[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
ptr[i]=arr[i];
```

How do i fix this issue? i want to send any array using a void pointer array
I have added the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define N 5
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef enum {FALSE,TRUE} BOOL;
BOOL Int_Sum(void* a, void* b, void* c)
{
    if (*(int*)a + *(int*)b == *(int*)c)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;

};
BOOL Float_sum(void*a, void* b, void* c)
{
    if (*(float*)a + *(float*)b == *(float*)c)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;

};
BOOL Sum(BOOL(*F)(void*, void*, void*), void** p_num, void* number)
{
    int i = 0,j=0;
    for (i = 0; i <N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j <N; j++)
        {
            if (j != i)
            {
                if (F(&p_num[i], &p_num[j], number))
                    return TRUE;
            }


        }
    }
    return FALSE;

}
int main()
{
    int num[] = { 3,5,23,5,6 }, i=0, value;
    float fnum[] = { 3.5,5.0,2.3,5.8,6.2 }, fvalue;
    void* p_num[N];
    float* f_pnt[N];
    BOOL* fpnt;
    fpnt=Int_Sum;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        p_num[i] = num[i];
    printf("\nPlease enter an integer number:");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    if (Sum(fpnt, p_num,&value )== TRUE)
        printf("There is such sum\n");
    else
        printf("There is no such sum\n");
    printf("\nPlease enter an integer number:");
    scanf("%f", &fvalue);
    fpnt = Float_sum;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        (float*)p_num[i] =fnum+i;
    }
    if (Sum(fpnt, p_num, &fvalue))
        printf("There is such sum\n");
    else printf("There is no such sum\n");



    return 0;

}
```

Having trouble with the funciton when i want to use the float array

**

Comment: What makes you say void pointers and float pointers are not the same size?

Comment: Surely `void*` and `float` could be different sizes, and it doesn't make sense to assign one to the other. But that's what you're doing here. Did you intend `ptr[i] = &arr[i]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "send any array"?  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [void\* is literally float, how to cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313658/void-is-literally-float-how-to-cast)

Comment: Well, i could have explained myself alot better, i have a function which intakes a array of void pointers and checks to see if there are identical things in the array. i have 2 arrays in my main, one of them is int , and the other one is float. i need to ASSIGN THE VOID POINTERS to point to the FLOAT ELEMENTS so  Void ptr[0]=float arr[0]. how do i accomplish this?

Comment: `(float*)p_num[i] =fnum+i;` --> `p_num[i] =fnum+i;`

Comment: This did not work, sadly i still get a wrong answer when i send the number 11.2 into the function (float function)

Comment: @Soske You are incorrect,  `11.2` should fail due to the binary nature of floating point.  Print each `float` with using `"%.20f"` to see why.

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong... a `void *` and a `float *` are exactly the same size.  The pointed thing is what is different, but not the pointer. BTW, why do you play with `void` pointers? That's like playing russian roulette by pleasure.  Please, don't involve us on that !!! 8)

Answer (score 1):

> How do i fix this issue?

Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.  That is how I found most code issues here.

---

At least these problems:

**Wrong type declaration for function pointer**

An *object* pointer `BOOL *fpnt` is not sufficient to certainly store a *function* pointer.  Use a function pointer.

```
//BOOL *fpnt;
BOOL (*fpnt)(void*, void*, void*);
```

**Wrong argument types in `F()`**

```
    // if (F(&p_num[i], &p_num[j], number))
    if (F(p_num[i], p_num[j], number))
```

**Casting hints something is wrong**

Cast causes code to fail to compile.  Cast not needed.

```
// (float*)p_num[i] =fnum+i;
p_num[i] = fnum+i;
```

**Assigning an `int` to a pointer**

Instead, assign the address of the `int`.

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  // p_num[i] = num[i];
  p_num[i] = &num[i];
```

---

> i know that a `void` ptr and `float` are not the same size so i cannot assign it in this manner `void[0]=float[0]`

Assigning a `float` to a pointer makes little sense.

Assigning a `float *` to `void *`:  It is also true that `float *` and `void *` *may* differ in size and encoding, yet that is not the key problem here.

---

Note that values like `2.3,5.8,6.2` are **not** encoded *exactly* as `float`.  Instead nearby values are used.  Code might not behave as hoped.

Add below to see why.

```
BOOL Float_sum(void *a, void *b, void *c) {
  printf("%.20f %.20f %.20f  %.20f\n", 
      *(float*) a, *(float*) b, *(float*) c, *(float*) a + *(float*) b);
  ...
```

Comment: All works !
Could u care to explain why int assign is
p_num[i]=&arr
but for float its
p_num[i]=arr+i 

Thanks alot!

Comment: @Soske There is no `p_num[i]=&arr` or `p_num[i]=&of_some_array_object` .  Question unclear or imprecise.

Comment: Why do i assign void *arr to int arr with an &, but when i assign void * to float arr with arr+i;

Comment: @Soske Please copy the line of code here as text and apply the question to that line.

Comment: Assigning Void *arr[5] to int arr[5] i use this code :    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        p_num[i] = &num[i];    But when i assign Void *arr[5] to float arr[5] i use this :     for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        p_num[i] = fnum+i;
    }

Comment: `p_num[i] = &num[i];` is equivalent to  `p_num[i] = num + i;` and `p_num[i] = fnum+i;` equivalent to `p_num[i] = &fnum[i];`.  Two different styles to do the same thing.  No significant difference. The original flawed code was corrected using the most similar style.

Comment: Got it , i appreciate the help bro!!